# Parallel sorting with std::sort and a custom iterator casts values

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm writing a sorting method that sorts two arrays simultaneously, based on the values in one of the arrays. I've used [this](https://artificial-mind.net/blog/2020/11/28/std-sort-multiple-ranges) as a reference and made a few minor changes (made the `operator*()` const, and added constructors for the class `ref`), so it compiles in MSVC/g++/clang.

After adding `std::execution::par` to enable parallel sorting, clang and g++ don't compile it anymore (but MSVC does). The final code and error can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WKz17v3YG). The errors in g++ and clang are similar:

> source:45:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const val' to 'const ref' for 1st argument
> bool operator<(ref const& a, val const& b)

This error can be resolved by implementing `bool operator<(val const& a, val const& b)`, but then the final values array holds empty strings. This can be resolved by removing the `move` operator from `operator val() &&`. However, the `move` operator was an important design decision for performance.

Question: Is there a way to keep the move operator?

So now it compiles in the online environment of godbolt.org, but not locally, because the installation of tbb affects the compilation steps. Tbb is installed locally and is necessary for actual parallel execution. The error is:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:435:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:215:11: error: no match for call to ‘(std::less<val>) (const ref&, ref)’
  215 |  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:48,
                 from tmp.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_function.h:385:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = val]’ <near match>
  385 |       operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_function.h:385:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:60,
                 from tmp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:215:11: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘const ref’ to ‘const val&’ [-fpermissive]
  215 |  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:42:2: note: candidate is: ‘ref::operator val() &&’ <near match>
   42 |  operator val() && { return {*key, *value}; }
      |  ^~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:42:2: note:   passing ‘const ref’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
```

Supplementary question: Why does it want to do a conversion if it can use `bool operator<(ref const& a, ref const& b)`?

Comment: `zip_iterator` might interest you (as [boost's one](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html))

Comment: Off the top, `sort_it` doesn't meet iterator requirements, and so passing it to `std::sort` exhibits undefined behavior. "**[forward.iterators]/1** A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if ... if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`" (where `T` is `value_type`).

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for pointing me in the direction of zip_operator. I found an interesting discussion [on stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/c17-zip-iterator-compatible-with-stdsort]).